# How do you post to a URL?

Tags: html, url, post, webhooks, ping

I would like to speak with a consultant on this topic.  Can someone point me in the right direction for Webhooks and Posting to a URL - Thank you

Comment: There is not enough information here for anyone to help you.

Comment: I have a Webform and the data .. I need to post to my Lead Distribution platform.. and it only accepts if the data is posted to a URL.

Comment: What language are you attempting this in? Can you provide any existing code for your current attempts and what you're trying to do? Welcome to StackOverflow, we do not provide full code solutions to your problems for you but rather guide you in the right path in order for you to figure out what you need to do however to do this, you need to provide more information and give examples with your code.

Comment: Ahh  I see.  I was just looking for some help.